# How to wait on file creation

Tags: java, file, io

My situation is as following:
I got a Java program, wich starts a perl script. 
The Perl script is generating a file, on which Java should continue working.
As by now, i had set a

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

to let Java wait for the file to be finished.
I was looking for an more elegant way to let Java check if the file exists and continue then. My last try was

```
Boolean waitforfile = true;  
while(waitforfile){
       File f = new File(pathtofile);
       if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { waitforfile=false; }
       }
```

But that one will get me stuck in a never ending loop. 
Is there any way else to do it?

Update :
On Suggestion, tried, process,WaitFor();
In

```
    public static String syscall(String call){
    String out = "";
    try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(call);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
      out=out+"\n"+line;
    }
    input.close();
    p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return out;
}
```

This one did not wait on my perl process to be closed.

Comment: Why don't you wait for the perl process to finish instead?

Comment: I have to admit, i don''t really know how i could wait on that with Runtime.exec in Java

Comment: Runtime.exec() returns a Process. And Process has a waitFor() method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29

Comment: um okay, seems to be something about my syscall or my perl is Buggy, as i am caught in a waiting for a while now

Comment: @JB Nizet : Updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way is to write the file to a temporary file name like `myscript.pl.tmp` and rename it when you are finished.  As rename is atomic, you won't see it in an incomplete state.

BTW You can use the WatchService to be notified when a file appears. [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: Well, i am not completely sure if i really get the first part of your answer. You mean i should use my code from up there and just change the perl script to write in an temporary file and then rename it ?

Comment: @chenino using a rename is an effective way to signal the file is complete.  An alternative is to wait for the perl script to finish if you are the one starting it.

Comment: Tried wait for Perl script, see update of the question. Will take a look at WatchService now

Answer (score 5):

As @peter-lawrey has mentioned, the correct way to go is `java.nio.file.WatchService`.

The following is a simple implementation for the specific (but common) case of waiting the creation of a file. This static method returns the basic file attributes of the target file (`creationTime` is among them), or `null` if the file did not show up.

```
public static BasicFileAttributes awaitFile(Path target, long timeout) 
    throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    final Path name = target.getFileName();
    final Path targetDir = target.getParent();

    // If path already exists, return early
    try {
        return Files.readAttributes(target, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    } catch (NoSuchFileException ex) {}

    final WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    try {
        final WatchKey watchKey = targetDir.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
        // The file could have been created in the window between Files.readAttributes and Path.register
        try {
            return Files.readAttributes(target, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        } catch (NoSuchFileException ex) {}
        // The file is absent: watch events in parent directory 
        WatchKey watchKey1 = null;
        boolean valid = true;
        do {
            long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            watchKey1 = watchService.poll(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (watchKey1 == null) {
                return null; // timed out
            }
            // Examine events associated with key
            for (WatchEvent<?> event: watchKey1.pollEvents()) {
                Path path1 = (Path) event.context();
                if (path1.getFileName().equals(name)) {
                    return Files.readAttributes(target, BasicFileAttributes.class);
                }
            }
            // Did not receive an interesting event; re-register key to queue
            long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - t0;
            timeout = elapsed < timeout? (timeout - elapsed) : 0L;
            valid = watchKey1.reset();
        } while (valid);
    } finally {
        watchService.close();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: does this pause Java code execution like Thread.Sleep()?

Comment: @Phil yes, call to `WatchService.poll(timeout, unit)` will suspend the running thread waiting for the next event. But, unlike `Thread.sleep`, the thread will wake up as soon as a relevant event shows up

Comment: oh wow, thank you for replying back to my question in this old post.  I will try out the WatchService

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the file exists (Files.exists()) in the directory or not using while loop. Continue the loop till it returns False, and get out of the loop once it finds the file in the directory.